# C memcpy issues with unsigned char array

Tags: c

I have a question about memcpy that I hope someone can answer. Here's a short demonstrative program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main (int argc, char **argv){
  unsigned char buffer[10];
  unsigned short checksum = 0x1234;
  int i;
  memset(buffer, 0x00, 10);
  memcpy(buffer, (const unsigned char*)&checksum, 2);
  for(i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
    printf("%02x",buffer[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

When I run this program, I get 34120000000000000000.
My question is why don't I get 12340000000000000000?

Thanks so much

Comment: what is the architecture of your machine ?

Answer (score 8):

You are getting 34120000000000000000 because you are on a little-endian system.  You would get 12340000000000000000 on a big-endian system. [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big-endian) gives a full discussion of big-endian vs. little-endian systems.

Answer (score 2):

little endian/big endian architecture ?
which mean that 2 byte of checksum is inverted.

It is just a guess, if my answer is not true Comment it and I will delete it.

Comment: Endianess is a good point, but I see the same results when I run this on two different machines, one an Intel P4 ant the other an AMD64 which I believe are little endian and big endian architectures, respectively.

Comment: AMD64 is little endian too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024951/does-my-amd-based-machine-use-little-endian-or-big-endian

Comment: @aarbear or motorola architecture or itanium which has support for both little endian and big endian

Answer (score 1):

Intel's CPUs are little endian, they store numbers little word first

This is apparently evidence that Intel don't do inhouse drug testing.

Comment: hahaha. no actually little endian has many advantages that big endian doesn't. just like 0-based indexing.

Comment: @Matt Joiner - STOP IT STOP IT NOW. Or you will be sent back to 1980 for time out.

Comment: @detly: Have we met before? Have you noticed a trend in my answers?

Comment: @Matt - I couldn't find a source for the quote, I thought it was some guy from Dec. Any idea?