# Why copying a byte array to a uint array changes the order of the data?

Tags: c#, arrays, data-conversion

Why Marshal.Copy changes the order of the bytes? It seams to convert to MSB (most significant byte).

Sample code:

```
string s = "abc 123";
byte[] data = StringToByteArray(s);
uint[] data2 = ByteArrayToUintArray(data);
//s[0] = a = 61
//data[0] = a = 61
//but data2[0] = " cba" = 0x20636261


    public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string str)
    {
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        return encoding.GetBytes(str);
    }

    public static uint[] ByteArrayToUintArray(byte[] data)
    {
        int lenght = (data.Length + 3) / 4;
        uint[] data2 = new uint[lenght];

        GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(data2, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        IntPtr ptr = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        //do your stuff
        Marshal.Copy(data, 0, ptr, data.Length);
        pinnedArray.Free();
        return data2;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumed your program runs on an Intel processor, the integer format is [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Endianness_and_hardware), which means the least significant byte comes first. So `0x20636261` is actually stored  in memory as

```
 0x61 0x62 0x63 0x20
```

which means `Marshal.Copy` did not change the byte order, you just misunderstood the correct order for how to decode the integer value into a sequence of bytes.

Comment: Is this a default behavior? I mean, can I trust that this will always happen in any PC processor?

Comment: @Pedro77: the wikipedia article (see link above) contains a list which processor types use little-endian format and which use big-endian.

Comment: According to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024951/does-my-amd-based-machine-use-little-endian-or-big-endian. All x86-64 processor use litle-endian

Comment: @Pedro77: Yes, and in the Wikipedia article, you find the same information there. But you asked for PC processors, not specificially Intel processors.

Comment: AMD != Intel. But still are x86-64 and litle-indian.